# How to log in to this website using requests library?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am writing a very simple web scraper, but I need to log-in to a particular website which requires to fill in a form.

The link to the website I am talking about: "https://odrabiamy.pl"

The form sends a POST request to this endpoint: "https://odrabiamy.pl/api/v1.3/sessions.json" with this payload:

```
{"user": {"login": "my email address","password": "my password"}}
```

I figured it out using Chrome Dev Tools.

The problem is with my code. I try to send a POST request with this payload, but the issue is that it returns an error and I don't know how to figure it out.

It returns this error:

```
{
    "message": "Nieznana metoda autentykacji"
}
```

It translates to "unknown authentication method".

I also checked a status code my request returns and it is 400.

[image: Program]

My code:

```py
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Podrabiamy:

    def __init__(self):
        self.login_url = "https://odrabiamy.pl/api/v1.3/sessions.json"
        self.data = {"user": {"login": "xxxxxxxx", "password": "xxxxxxx"}}
        self.headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

    def login(self):
        with requests.Session() as session:
            response = session.post(self.login_url, data=json.dumps(self.data), headers=self.headers)
            print(response.content)
            print(response.status_code)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    podrabiamy = Podrabiamy()
    podrabiamy.login()
```

Comment: Is there nothing else to the request than the payload? The Chrome developer tools can let you find that out, right?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to attach the "user-agent" key with value from the response header I figured out using Chrome Dev Tools, but that didn't work. I also tried to play with multiple response headers, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried to attach the cookie?

Comment: are u sure it doesn't pass the information as body instead than data?

Comment: Send a GET request to the main URL before the POST request in the same session. Also, I recommend passing all the request headers.